# Arch: cannot make setxkbmap persistant

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout

I followed this [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Using_setxkbmap) but I didn't get it work at boot automatically, I mean every time I boot I have to run this command:

```
setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout fr,ara -variant ,azerty -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

I'm using Deepin DE and this is /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbLayout" "fr,ara"
    Option "XkbModel" "pc104"
    Option "XkbVariant" ",azerty"
    Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```

**~/.xinitrc**:

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then

    xrdb -merge $sysresources

fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then

    xrdb -merge "$userresources"

fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi

twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
exec startdde
```

Answer (score 2):

Before the check for `"$sysmodmap"` in your `.xinitrc`, add the `setxkbmap` line.  The modified file might look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi

setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout fr,ara -variant ,azerty -option grp:alt_shift_toggle

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"
fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi

twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
exec startdde
```